# ORDER BY FIELD not working - error message

Tags: mysql

I have this Select:

```
SELECT pts_name
FROM   products_tecspecs
WHERE  pts_id IN ( 5275, 21, 5276, 5277,
                   5278, 49, 5279 )
ORDER  BY FIELD (pts_id, 5275, 21, 5276, 5277, 5278, 49, 5279)
```

I am trying to get the result and order it the way I want. I found [this](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/209784) answer but got this error: #1305 - FUNCTION database_name.FIELD does not exist

I am trying to get specifics results with IN (that's working), but sorting the way I want.

Help you be apreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the space between the function and the parenthesis: `FIELD (`
MySQL parser does not like spaces there. Use:

```
FIELD(pts_id, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try subquery to order by records in custom order

```
SELECT pts_name
FROM (SELECT pts_name,
             CASE pts_id 
                 WHEN 5275 THEN 1
                 WHEN 21 THEN 2
                 WHEN 5276 THEN 3
                 WHEN 5277 THEN 4
                 WHEN 5278 THEN 5
                 WHEN 49 THEN 6
                 WHEN 5279 THEN 7
             END AS sort_order
      FROM products_tecspecs 
      WHERE pts_id IN ( 5275, 21, 5276, 5277, 5278, 49, 5279)
    ) a
ORDER BY a.sort_order ASC ;
```